# Property never null c#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, refactoring

When refactoring code, I come up with instances like the following

```
private string _property = string.Empty;
public string Property
{
    set { _property = value ?? string.Empty); }
}
```

Later on in a method I see the following:

```
if (_property != null)
{
    //...
}
```

Assuming that `_property` is only set by the setter of `Property`, is this code redundant?

I.e is there any way, through reflection wizardry or other methods that `_property` can ever be null?

Comment: Cosmic rays and hardware bugs could always cause the value to be null. When I see something like this I attribute it to "An Abundance of Caution." There are lots of ways the internal field could get a null (serialization of input, e.g.), but most them are pretty exceptional and should be clear from context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming that _property is only set by the setter of Property, is this
>   code redundant?

Exactly, it is redundant. This is the actual purpose of Properties. We shouldn't access the fields of a class directly. We should access them using a Property. So in the corresponding setter, we can embed any logic and we can rest assure that each time we try to set a value this logic would be verified once more.This argument holds even for the methods of a class. In a method we must use the properties and not the actual fields. Furthermore, when we want to read the value of a field, we should make use of the corresponding getter.

In general, properties enhances the concept of encapsulation, which is one of the pillars of object oriented programming OOP.

Many times there isn't any logic that should be applied when we want to set a value. Take for instance the following example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

We have declared a class for representing a Customer. A Customer object should have three properties an `Id`, a `FirstName` and a `LastName`.

An immediate question, when someones read this class is why should someone make use of properties here?

The answer is again the same, they provide a mechanism of encapsulation. But let's consider how can this help us in the long run. Let's say that one day someone decides that the first name of a customer should be a string of length less than 20. If the above class had been declared as below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

then we should check for the length of `FirstName` in each instance we had created ! Otherwise, if we had picked the declaration with the properties, we could just easily make use of [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx)

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and that's it. Another approach it could be the following:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName 
    { 
        get { return firstName }
        set
        {
            if(value!=null && value.length<20)
            {
                firstName = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The first name must have at maxium 20 characters", "value");
            }
        } 
    }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Consider both of the above approaches with having to revisit all your codebase and make this check. It's crystal clear that properties win.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible through reflection.  Nevertheless, I wouldn't worry about reflection -- people using reflection to defeat the design of your class is not something I worry about.

There is, however, something I do worry about: the phrase "Assuming that _property is only set by the setter of Property" is key.  You are preventing users of your class from setting property to null.

You do not prevent, however, yourself or some other maintainer of your class from forgetting to only use the property INSIDE your class.  In fact, your example has some one checking the field from inside the class rather than the property itself.... which means that, within your class, access comes from both the field and the property.

In most cases (where the problem could only come from inside the class) I would use an assertion and assert the field is not null.

If I really, really, really wanted to make sure that it wasn't null (barring reflection or people hell-bent on breaking things), you could try something like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string example = "Spencer the Cat";
        UsesNeverNull neverNullUser = new UsesNeverNull(example);
        Console.WriteLine(neverNullUser.TheString);
        neverNullUser.TheString = null;
        Debug.Assert(neverNullUser.TheString != null);
        Console.WriteLine(neverNullUser.TheString);
        neverNullUser.TheString = "Maximus the Bird";
        Console.WriteLine(neverNullUser.TheString);
    }


}

public class UsesNeverNull
{
    public string TheString
    {
        get { return _stringValue.Value; } 
        set { _stringValue.Value = value; }
    }

    public UsesNeverNull(string s)
    {
        TheString = s;
    }

    private readonly NeverNull<string> _stringValue = new NeverNull<string>(string.Empty, str => str ?? string.Empty); 
}

public class NeverNull<T> where T : class
{
    public NeverNull(T initialValue, Func<T, T> nullProtector)
    {
        if (nullProtector == null)
        {
            var ex = new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nullProtector));
            throw ex;
        }
        _value = nullProtector(initialValue);
        _nullProtector = nullProtector;
    } 

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _nullProtector(_value); }
        set { _value = _nullProtector(value); }
    }
    private T _value;
    private readonly Func<T, T> _nullProtector;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is basically redundant. However, if it were mission critical or if for some reason it caused terrible side effects, it could remain. It is hard to tell, but part of your question was "can reflection change this value to null" to which the answer is yes and can be seen here in this linqpad demo

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new Test();
    test.Property = "5";
    Console.WriteLine(test.Property);//5

    FieldInfo fieldInfo = test.GetType().GetField("_property",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(test, null);
    Console.WriteLine(test.Property);//null
}

public class Test
{
    private string _property = string.Empty;
    public string Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value ?? string.Empty; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but look, I needed that one of my string properties never came up in null.

So I did this, and It worked for me

```
public string Operation { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

In this way the default value is a string empty, but never null.

Comment: Please give a feedback, if you're going to vote down ‍♂️